# If you have a closed tube with a speaker at one end. Do you then have a pressure node at the speaker and at the end of the tube?

Tags: waves, pressure, acoustics

If you have a closed tube with a speaker at one end. Do you then have a pressure node at the speaker and at the end of the tube?

A standing wave will develop in the tube. Will there be a node at the speaker?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loudspeaker attached to cylinder - closed or open?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462200/loudspeaker-attached-to-cylinder-closed-or-open)